# How to dynamic change the component type in FieldArray

Tags: redux-form

I have a FieldArray, and I want to change one of the Field's component type when adding a new line of Fields for it ( `this.props.array.push("xxx", { obj })`).

For example, I have a value named summaryNo.

When summaryNo === 0, I want the Field became a Picker. Else, as a simeple input Field.

Is that possible? I gave a try like the below codes:

`export const renderInputOrPicker = ({ input, label, children, ...custom) => {
    if (input.value instanceof Array && input.value[0] === "toBeAPicker") {
        return (
            <Picker mode="dropdown" {...input}
                    selectedValue={input.value[1]}
                    onValueChange={(value) => {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            input.onChange(value);
                        }, 10);
                    }} children={children} {...custom} />
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <Item regular>
                <Input {...input} />
            </Item>
        );
    }
};`

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I have figured a way out. I just don't need the input Field. What I want to do is to have a Field that can display "true" or "false" and can be controlled by the disable status.

The Picker Field can do that already. Which means I can let it read-only or editable and showing the current value.

All in all, I am still looking for the answer, a better solution for this redux form scenario!

Thanks.